# Adding columns and returning sum to select list in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm having trouble adding three columns: first name, second name and surname together for example "Bob Bobby Smith" and returning them to display in select list item in Oracle Apex. Can't find anything on the internet, i'm not even sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `||`, the string concatenation operator?

```
select (firstname || ' ' || secondname || ' ' || surname) as fullname
from t;
```